# Copy and Paste Column Regardless of Worksheet Open

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have 3 worksheets in my workbook ("SheetJS", "Sheet1", and "Sheet2").

I want the macro to copy and paste the values of Sheet1 from Column K to Column L. 
My code works but copies and pastes the columns on whichever worksheet is open/active.

I want the macro to code and paste the values only in "Sheet1" regardless of which one of the worksheets is open.

Any tips would help.

Thanks!

```
Sub Copy_K_to_L_2()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
          Columns("K:K").Copy Destination:=Columns("L:L")

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `Columns("K:K")....` is an `Implicit` reference to the `ActiveSheet`. You'll need to be `Explicit` about your sheet reference. In your case > put a `.` in front of `Columns("K:K")...` and `Columns("L:L")`. However, if you want to transfer just values, you don't need to use `Copy/Paste` at all but a value transfer would do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to edit your existing line:

```
Columns("K:K").Copy Destination:= Thisworkbook.sheets("Sheet1").Columns("L:L")
```

Comment: Rather: `.Columns("K:K").Copy .Columns("L:L")`. Right now, your first `Columns` is still an `Implicit` reference to the `ActiveSheet`. And OP got a good `With` statement refering to the `Sheet` object she wants to use.

Comment: Thanks guys that really helped! I had no idea implicit and explicit references existed.